# Jquery each loop through nested json

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to use a simple Json file and call multiple select boxes. I have one static select box which is the following:

```
<select>
<option value="first">This is the first</option>
<option value="second">This is the second</option>
<option value="third">This is the third</option>
<option value="fourth">This is the fourth</option>
<option value="fifth">This is the fifth</option>
</select>
```

This determines what the output is - I am using a JSON file like so.

```
{
    "first": [
        {
            "london": [
                {
                    "id": "london",
                    "name": "London UK",
                    "london": [
                        {
                            "id": "london",
                            "name": "London UK"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "secondLondon",
                            "name": "Second London"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "second": [
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when `first` is clicked on the select box, it does nto return `id = london` or `name = London UK`.

```
$("#form").on('change', function() {
     $("select#preferred_study_location").html('');
        var things = options[$(this).val()];
        var thingstring = '';
        $.each(things, function(i, item) {
          console.log(things[i]);
        });
    $('#preferred_study_location').html(thingstring);
});
```

Comment: What does it log instead? Nothing? What's the value of `things`? What does `typeof things` return?

Comment: So when i click on the first option, the right array is being selected. like so: `Object {london: Array[1], london: Array[1], west: Array[1], east: Array[1], south: Array[1]…}` But the call is wrong. `typeof things` returns `undefined`.

Comment: What is `options`..? What is `#form`? What is `"select#preferred_study_location` if you're using an `id` selector, then adding the tag selector doesn't make any sense... Anyway, is that the select we're talking about, or is it something else..?

Comment: More over, you're note at all modifying `thingstring` then what's the point in replacing an elements `html()` with an empty string which you already emptied..? finally, why do you have london inside london and so on..? Are you sure this is the json structure..? Maybe if you properly explain what you're trying to do, you'll get a better solution...

Comment: @SophieRhodes Created jsfiddle which utilizes pattern at OP , yet as pointed out by @TJ , what is expected return value of `thingstring` ? `things[i]` would return `Object {london: Array[1]}` - though , there not appear corresponding `html` at `select` elements to further filter properties , values within `things[i]` . What is expected result ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

html

```
<form id="form">
<select>
    <option>select</option>
<option value="first" data-value="london">This is the first</option>
<option value="second" data-value="wales">This is the second</option>
<option value="third" data-value="surrey">This is the third</option>
<option value="fourth" data-value="newcastle">This is the fourth</option>
<option value="fifth" data-value="liverpool">This is the fifth</option>
</select>
    <output for="form" id="preferred_study_location"></output>
</form>
```

js

```
$("#form").on("change", function(e) {
        var output = $("[for=form]", this)
        , val = e.target.value
        , data = $("[value=" + val + "]", this).data("value")
        , things = options[val]
        , thingstring = "";
        output.html("");
        $.each(things, function(i, item) {
            console.log(things[i][data][i]);
            thingstring = things[i][data][i].name;
        });
        output.html(thingstring);
});
```

```js
var options = {
    "first": [
        {
            "london": [
                {
                    "id": "london",
                    "name": "London UK",
                    "london": [
                        {
                            "id": "london",
                            "name": "London UK"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "secondLondon",
                            "name": "Second London"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
        "second": [
        {
            "wales": [
                {
                    "id": "wales",
                    "name": "Wales UK",
                    "wales": [
                        {
                            "id": "wales",
                            "name": "Wales UK"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "secondWales",
                            "name": "Second Wales"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
        "third": [
        {
            "surrey": [
                {
                    "id": "surrey",
                    "name": "Surrey UK",
                    "surrey": [
                        {
                            "id": "surrey",
                            "name": "Surrey UK"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "secondSurrey",
                            "name": "Second Surrey"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
        "fourth": [
        {
            "newcastle": [
                {
                    "id": "newcastle",
                    "name": "Newcastle UK",
                    "newcastle": [
                        {
                            "id": "newcastle",
                            "name": "Newcastle UK"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "secondNewcastle",
                            "name": "Second Newcastle"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
        "fifth": [
        {
            "liverpool": [
                {
                    "id": "liverpool",
                    "name": "Liverpool UK",
                    "liverpool": [
                        {
                            "id": "liverpool",
                            "name": "Liverpool UK"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "secondLiverpool",
                            "name": "Second Liverpool"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
$("#form").on("change", function(e) {
        var output = $("[for=form]", this)
        , val = e.target.value
        , data = $("[value=" + val + "]", this).data("value")
        , things = options[val]
        , thingstring = "";
        output.html("");
        $.each(things, function(i, item) {
            console.log(things[i][data][i]);
            thingstring = things[i][data][i].name;
        });
    output.html(thingstring);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
<select>
    <option>select</option>
<option value="first" data-value="london">This is the first</option>
<option value="second" data-value="wales">This is the second</option>
<option value="third" data-value="surrey">This is the third</option>
<option value="fourth" data-value="newcastle">This is the fourth</option>
<option value="fifth" data-value="liverpool">This is the fifth</option>
</select>
    <output for="form" id="preferred_study_location"></output>
</form>
```